# Trying to find the first missing positive by using the in-loop variable

Tags: python, list

Given a list of integers, I want to find the first missing positive.  My idea was to do it using the variable within the for loop to avoid clutter.  Here is what I did:

```
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        sort_list = sorted(nums)
        holder = 0
        item = 1

        for item in range(len(sort_list)):

            if sort_list[item] != item:
                holder = item

        return holder
```

So here is what I did.  First, I sorted the list in ascending order.  Then I initialized 2 variables `holder = 0` and `item = 1`.  Because the given list is suppose to start at 1, I tried to start the for-loop at 1 as well.  The reason is that if I was given a list like `[7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 3]`, the first missing positive has to be one.  Anyways, then I tried to loop through every item in the list to see if it compares `item` and if not, I assigned `holder = item` and returned `holder`.  However, it ended up returning 0 when my input was `[1, 2, 0]` when it should've returned 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the numbers to a set then check successively 1, 2, 3, etc. to see if they are in the set:

```
def first_missing_positive(number_list):
    number_set = set(number_list)
    for n in range(1, len(number_list) + 1):
        if n not in number_set:
            return n
    return None

print(first_missing_positive([7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8]))
```

Prints:

```
4
```

**Another approach:**

All the numbers 1, 2, ... len(input list) are added to a set. Then the numbers in the passed list are removed from this set and the smallest number in the set remaining is returned. This could be an improvement over the first solution, especially when the first positive number missing is towards the end (high positive value) since looping in Python might be slower than the set calculations done in its C-language implementation.

```
def first_missing_positive(number_list):
    return  min(set(range(1, len(number_list) + 1)) - set(number_list))
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in a little different way:

```
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        max = len(nums)

        for i in range(1,max+2):
            if i not in nums:
                return i
```

you can just check if the current number from a iteration is in the list, it doesn't have to be sorted.

range is from 1 to max+2, because if you got a list like [1,2,3,4] it has to count from 1 to 5, to find the 5 as missing number.

Comment: Thank you man. I really appreciate the help. I've upvoted your answer and if you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you give `holder` a value (0) in the beginning, so if you don't find any missing value, it will return 0. That'd solve your problem:

```py
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        sort_list = sorted(nums)
        holder = None

        for item in range(len(sort_list)):

            if sort_list[item] != item:
                holder = item

        return holder if holder is not None else item+1
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. I've upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little simplified, though if inputs are large lists, you should ignore this answer

```py
from operator import eq
def firstMissingPositive(nums):
    l = list(map(eq, nums, range(1, len(nums)+1)))
    return l.index(False) + 1 if False in l else -1
```

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the help.  I've given you an upvote for your time. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `set`:

```
def missingPos(x):
    y = set(range(1,max(x)+2))
    return min(y-set(x))

print(missingPos([7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 3]))
print(missingPos([1,2,0]))
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

A better solution would be to use iterators, that will be memory efficient for calculation with large lists:

```
def missingPos(x):
    generator = (i for i in range(1,max(x)+2) if i not in x)
    print(next(generator))
missingPos([1,2,0])
missingPos([7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 3])
```

Output:

```
3
1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I've upvoted your answer. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?